# Using pandas to convert string timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've been attempting to use `pandas.to_datetime` to convert between timestamp formats in my code base, however when provided with a string input sometimes `pandas` does not seem to extract the UTC offset correctly:

Here is a correct conversion, the UTC offset is correctly captured as reflected in the Timestamp object:

```
In[76]: pd.to_datetime('2014-04-09T15:29:59.999993-0500', utc=True)
Out[76]: Timestamp('2014-04-09 20:29:59.999993+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Here is an alternate string representation which is still a valid [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime strings but the UTC offset of `-0500` seems to be ignored:

```
In[77]: pd.to_datetime('2014-04-09T152959.999993-0500', utc=True)
Out[77]: Timestamp('2014-04-09 15:29:59.999993+0000', tz='UTC')
```

On the other hand the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package handles things fine:

```
In[78]: dateutil.parser.parse('2014-04-09T152959.999993-0500')
Out[78]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 9, 15, 29, 59, 999993, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

I could certainly use `dateutil` but is there some reason that `pandas.to_datetime` does not handle different ISO date time strings correctly.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Using Python 2.7.6 and `pandas 0.13.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using pandas 0.14.0: both calls to `pd.to_datetime` return the correct, timezone-aware Timestamp:

```
In [72]: pd.__version__
Out[72]: '0.14.0'

In [69]: pd.to_datetime('2014-04-09T152959.999993-0500', utc=True)
Out[69]: Timestamp('2014-04-09 20:29:59.999993+0000', tz='UTC')

In [70]: pd.to_datetime('2014-04-09T15:29:59.999993-0500', utc=True)
Out[70]: Timestamp('2014-04-09 20:29:59.999993+0000', tz='UTC')

In [71]: dateutil.parser.parse('2014-04-09T152959.999993-0500').astimezone(pytz.utc)
Out[71]: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 9, 20, 29, 59, 999993, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```